# Change variable X & Y value based on scroll wheel event across browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to listen to the scroll wheel event to get the "expected number of pixels scrolled" in a deltaX and deltaY value, and this across browser.
I am surprised about how few documentation and libraries there is to make this.
(only the Mozilla MDN even talks about the "wheel" event).

I found two scripts supposed to make this work across browser but I can't make any of those operate properly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/wheel
On this page "Listening to this event across browser" section provides a script supposed to solves this issue. 
I get this error

```
wheel.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: elem[_addEventListener] is not a function.
```

and also

https://github.com/anvaka/wheel/blob/master/index.js
With this one, just as the other one I get errors too :

```
wheel.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
index.js:144 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Can someone manages to make it work or have another solution ?

Comment: check this first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715496/binding-to-the-scroll-wheel-when-over-a-div

Comment: I do believe that the answers provided there mention no support for deltaX (and are basically about detecting if scrolling down / up as a boolean, but not about returning actual pixels value.) I don't mean to be lazy. I would dive into the code but I just feel like browser compatibility is a mess with this wheel event. I mentionned two script that were supposed to account all of this by creating a method. This hosted on platforms supposed to serve as reference  (mozilla MDN, github/npm). I just can't get them working.

Comment: The MDN example is working perfectly, as expected. Have a look a this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PKMemY?editors=1111)

Comment: You should provide the code which trigger those errors. Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What... You are right.  
https://codepen.io/rsepierre/pen/ZJgodo/ (method is used at the script's bottom)
Weird thing though in my codepen, if i set an any other element than "window"  as an element target : frame, origin, $('body') . I get the error. If i put "window" back it works as expected. (Though I won't be able to define "where" on the page it will / won't work.

Comment: For that MDN example, the element you pass on has to exist and beeing "scrollable". And if you want to get them from a jQuery element, add `[0]` to it. Like `$("body")[0]`. Remember that jQuery is a "superset" of JavaScript. ;)

Comment: frame[0], origin[0]. It defenitly did the trick... thanks. Usualy I manage to debug this but the console error was somewhat confusing to me. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved thanks to @Louys Patrice Bessette's advice.

The method provided on Mozilla's MDN website defenitly works as expected:
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Listening_to_this_event_across_browser

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: elem[_addEventListener] is not a function.
```

Can be due to wrong element being targeted. If using jQuery donc forget to specify `$('element')[0]`

The codepen provided by @Louys Patrice Bessette shows the method in action.
https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PKMemY?editors=1111

I hope this will be useful for others.